# Parse `uptime` for just the duration

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep, cut

When I run the command "uptime" on my Mac I get this output:

```
19:52  up 14 mins, 2 users, load averages: 2.95 4.19 4.31
```

This changes slightly depending on how long the system is up, adding hours and then days. Thus I would like to remove the first word plus space, and 4 characters before "users".

Making `19:52  up 14 mins, 2 users, load averages: 2.95 4.19 4.31`

this:

```
up 14 min
```

Or

```
8:03 up 52 days, 20:47, 3 users, load averages: 1.36 1.42 1.40
```

this:

```
up 52 days, 20:47
```

Or:

```
22:19 up 54 days, 1 min, 4 users, load averages: 2.08 2.06 2.27
```

this:

```
up 54 days, 1 min
```

So far the furthest I can get is using this: `uptime | cut -d " " -f2- |  sed 's/users.*//'` but that is still giving me a space before "up" and I still need to remove 4 characters at the end of the string. Can someone educate me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
sed -E 's/.*(up.*), [[:digit:]]+ user.*/\1/'
```

#### Examples

These are the examples from the question:

```
$ cat upfile
19:52  up 14 mins, 2 users, load averages: 2.95 4.19 4.31
8:03 up 52 days, 20:47, 3 users, load averages: 1.36 1.42 1.40
22:19 up 54 days, 1 min, 4 users, load averages: 2.08 2.06 2.27
```

The sed command produces:

```
$ sed -E 's/.*(up.*), [[:digit:]]+ user.*/\1/' <upfile
up 14 mins
up 52 days, 20:47
up 54 days, 1 min
```

#### How it works

We use one substitute command:

```
s/.*(up.*), [[:digit:]]+ user.*/\1/
```

- The first `.*` matches from the beginning of the line.
- `(up.*)` matches the word up and text that follows and saves it in group 1.
- `, [[:digit:]]+ users` matches a comma, followed by a space, followed by one or more digits, followed by a space, followed by the string `users`.
- The second `.*` matches everything after `user`.

We replace all of that with group 1, denoted `\1`.

#### Compatibility

This above should work on both BSD/OSX and modern Linux. On very old Linux, one may need to replace `-E` with `-r`:

```
sed -r 's/.*(up.*), [[:digit:]]+ user.*/\1/'
```

#### Perl version

```
$ perl -pe 's/.*(up.*), [[:digit:]]+ user.*/$1/' <upfile
up 14 mins
up 52 days, 20:47
up 54 days, 1 min
```

Comment: This works exactly how I want it to function in terminal, but I am putting it in coffee script and I am getting a "octal escape sequences are not allowed" error. Could you by any chance provide a workaround?

Comment: @Tony I have never used `coffee` but my guess would be that it is objecting to `\1`.  Try replacing it with`\\1`?

Comment: @Tony I just added an equivalent perl script which doesn't use a backslash at all.   Try it if you are still having problems with the sed command.

Comment: Thanks so much. The code is exactly what I asked for however, one problem. I just noticed if I close terminal it drops from 2 users to 1 user (singular, instead of plural). Any ideas?

Comment: I'm a bit tired, I changed users to user and it seemed to do the job! Thanks!

Comment: @Tony Very good.  Also, good observation on `users` vs `user`.  I updated the answer to use just `user`.

Answer (score 3):

I use this (adapt to include units if required):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

    BEGIN {
      while ("uptime" | getline)
        gsub(/,/,"")
        if (NF==10)
          print $3
        else if (NF==11)
          print $3,$4
        else if (NF==12)
          print $3,$4,$5
        else
          print $3,$4,$5,$6
      close("uptime")
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but what I am doing is much easier to do with just a single command.

Comment: @Tony You are actually using two commands and processes, where the awk call is a single one...

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry - I meant with a single line of commands. This way works great though.